# regex for breadcrumb in php

Tags: php, regex

I am currently building breadcrumb. It works for example for

http://localhost/researchportal/proposal/

```
    <?php
            $url_comp = explode('/',substr($url,1,-1));
            $end = count($url_comp);        
            print_r($url_comp);
            foreach($url_comp as $breadcrumb) {                     
            $landing="http://localhost/";
            $surl .= $breadcrumb.'/';                               
                if(--$end)
                 echo '
                 <a href='.$landing.''.$surl.'>'.$breadcrumb.'</a>&raquo;';
                else
                 echo '
                 <a href='.$landing.''.$surl.' class="active">'.$breadcrumb.'</a>';
                };?>
```

But when I typed in `http://localhost////researchportal////proposal//////////`

All the formatting was gone as it confuses my code.

I need to have the site path in an array like `([1]->researchportal, [2]->proposal)`
regardless of how many slashes I put.

So can `$url_comp = explode('/',substr($url,1,-1));` be turned into a regular expression to get my desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex.  Look at htmlentities() and stripslashes() in the PHP manual.  A regex will return a boolean value of whatever it says, and won't really help you achieve what you are trying to do.  All the regex can let you do is say if the string matches the regex do something.  If you put in a regex requiring at least 2 characters between each slash, then any time anyone puts more than one consecutive slash in there, the if statement will stop.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Found this on the php manual.

It uses simple str_replace statements, modifying this should achieve exactly what your post was asking.

```
    <?
    function stripslashes2($string) {
        $string = str_replace("\\\"", "\"", $string);
        $string = str_replace("\\'", "'", $string);
        $string = str_replace("\\\\", "\\", $string);
        return $string;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Alright, good luck with your project.  I've added a function to my answer which I found on the stripslashes page, looks like its exactly what you want, remove all but one slash.